# cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: Unable to connect [..] timed out

Tags: python, cassandra, timeout, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-driver

I am trying to access a remote Cassandra cluster using python [`cassandra-driver`](https://pypi.org/project/cassandra-driver/) like this:

```
cluster = Cluster(['192.168.19.1'], port=9042)
session = cluster.connect()
```

However, it gives me:

```
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers',
'192.168.19.1': error(None, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.19.1', 9042)].
Last error: timed out")})
```

My Cassandra cluster on `nodetool status` shows:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                                  Rack
UN  192.168.19.1  239,55 KiB  256          67,0%             e45b9451-0081-4b12-9acb-1bc9   92953846  rack1
UN  192.168.19.2  263,95 KiB  256          63,8%             662df0f8-4209-4b06-9d46-f558   ad10ff0a  rack1
UN  192.168.19.3  293,59 KiB  256          69,2%             aa00fc80-6a8a-4bb0-8645-ef3f   58a72754  rack1
```

For example - my `cassandra.yaml` parameters on the 192.168.19.1 host are as follows:

```
rpc_address: 192.168.19.1

listen_address: 192.168.19.1

native_transport_port: 9042

start_native_transport: true
```

What could be the reason of the problem?

Comment: Did you mention keyspace?

Comment: did you check that the port is really available, with something like: `telnet IP 9042`, etc.

Comment: Are you in the same subnet ? From which IP are you accessing?

Comment: @ChakriStark I just noticed I am in different subnet. And I was using its private IP 192.168.19.1 to access it. Should I change the cassandra.yaml file of each of the node with the following:
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: <public ip address>
And then do cluster = Cluster(['<public ip>'], port=9042) session = cluster.connect() ?

Comment: Then it will become Ec2Snitch configuration. It should work with present configuration that you are using.. I am using C driver and its working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase connection timeout, it may be surprisingly long even on the same host (not to mention your remote one).

```py
conn_timeout_ms = 200

cas_cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['192.168.19.1'], 
                      port=9042,
                      connect_timeout=conn_timeout_ms / 1000 # ms -> s
                      )

cas_session = cas_cluster.connect()
```